# Database supported with react-native-windows application?

Tags: mysql, database, react-native, sqlite, react-native-windows

I am trying to build a windows application with **react-native-windows**,
I have tried react-native-sqlite-storage and react-native-sqlite-2 npm packages but they are denying to support windows application.

Can someone please help me with which DB is supported for react-native-windows application ?

Trying to have a local Database in my windows application.

Comment: I am also looking for same solution